# Cant get with a jquery function to absolute-pos a div working for iphone

Tags: jquery, iphone, css, css-position

This is the function i use to reposition the #nav div
 in the middle (vertical) of the window

```
function RepositionNav(){
            var windowHeight = $window.height(); //get the height of the window
            var navHeight = $('#nav').height() / 2;
            var windowCenter = (windowHeight / 2); 
            var newtop = windowCenter - navHeight;
            $('#nav').css({"top": newtop}); //set the new top position of the navigation list
    }
```

this is where i reposition while scrolling on the window

```
$window.bind('scroll', function(){ //when the user is scrolling...

                RepositionNav();
});
```

It works fine, **but not** in iphone...
I mean, it disappears as users scroll down :? (stays on its original position,  top)

Any idea why?

Thanks a lot

Comment: staying on top is acting like position is fixed, if you prefix a `.css({"position":"absolute"})` to the chain does it then work?

Comment: well, i actually have it position:absolute in my CSS stylesheet, but i'll try that aswel!

Comment: Try putting an alert in the scroll-method to see if it get's fired at all.

Comment: i will try that, too, but as i said it works fine (but not in iphone)

Comment: checked, the alert is show but the #nav its not repositioned... :( any other?

Answer (score 1):

Seems silly, but make sure you do + "px" on the `.css()` assignment for `top`.

iPhone might handle it's window height differently.  I'd output some debugging information so you can verify that the iPhone is reporting/getting the correct values.

**edit 5/19/11 9:35am est**

In looking at your original question, and the comments you made about the iPhone reporting 240px no matter how much you scroll..it makes sense that it'd report 240px.  Your navHeight is a fixed value, and your windowHeight is a fixed value, so you will always get the same `newtop` value when you subtract them.  You need to take into account the scrolling offset of the page - try using the `window.scrollYOffset` value in conjunction with your equation, like so:

```
var windowHeight = $window.height(),
    navHeight = $('#nav').height() / 2,
    windowCenter = (windowHeight / 2),
    newTop = (windowCenter - navHeight) + window.scrollYOffset;
    /* we use the scrollYOffset to normalize your newTop value to
       the current top of the viewPort, based on how far the user has
       scrolled down on the page.
    */

$('#nav').css({ top: newTop });
```

Comment: ahá! didn't thought about that! but it doesn't seem to make any difference (but maybe my iphones cache it's playing with me...)

Comment: well, did an alert(newpos+ "px") and it shows 240pxpx so the + "px" is not needed, the problem is that is showing same 240 no matter how much i scroll, how is this possible? any clue? cheers!!

Comment: are you having the same problem?

Comment: almos same result (before i had the #nav in the vertical-center and now its in the very top of the window), but it 'doesnt follow the scroll', thanks a lot for your time, though. if you have an iphone and you would like to try please click http://bit.ly/llH34z

Comment: when i view the page in chrome and safari it seems like the nav's position is set to fixed. do you change it to absolute for an iOS Safari client?

Comment: how do i do that? i got it 'fixed' now (for all of them)

Comment: @Jim Rubenstein, excuse me, so you suggest changing to absolute? ios4 supports it?? thank you